# Making two div of same size

Tags: html, css

I have two columns in a row. I want the height of row to be the height of smaller column and the larger one will be scrollable. Is it possible to do without using javascript?

```
<div class="row">


  <div class="col-md-8">

    <span style="color:white">Wash-type</span>
    <form>
      <!-- dummy data-->
      <label class="customCheckbox">
        <input type="radio" name="r1" value="r1"><span>Option 1</span></label>
      <label class="customCheckbox">
        <input type="radio" name="r1" value="r2"><span>Option 2</span></label>
      <label class="customCheckbox">
        <input type="radio" name="r1" value="r2"><span>option 3</span></label>
      <label class="customCheckbox">
        <input type="radio" name="r1" value="r2"><span>Option 4</span></label>
    </form>


  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4" style="oveflow:scroll;">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>

          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Service Option</th>
            <th>Price</th>

          </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </div>
  </div>

  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: show your work or code

Comment: Without having tested your code, I see at least one typo :
`<div class="col-md-4" style="oveflow:scroll;">`
should be written
`<div class="col-md-4" style="overflow:scroll;">` ('r' is missing in 'overflow')

Comment: That is a typo only while editing code.Overflow does't work as height is not fixed for row.If I set display to flex it takes the height of longer column. And if I fix the height, i guess it will effect the responsiveness.

Comment: @KrrishRaj Do you have style to go along with those classes? Also it's a minor mistake, but the end tags for the divs on the bottom should be after the end tag of the table I think.

Comment: @zer00ne Thanx for your comcern. This is just a rough code to check if things are working. I had to delete a lot of code in between while uploading the code as page was saying "too much code, add some details", so elements have been shuffled. Sorry :)

Comment: @KrrishRaj yeah I know what you mean, that's why I don't even bother to try to ask questions, my site is mired in layers and layers of code. :\

Comment: @KrrishRaj That's posible without javascript. See [this codepen](http://codepen.io/woestijnrog/pen/ojawpM) for a bare-bones example.

Comment: @ woestijnrog That does the job. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

This is JS solution if you don't find other one https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/21/

**JS**

```
$(window).resize(setHeight);
$(document).ready(setHeight);

function setHeight() {
    var height = $('.left').height();
    $('.row, .right').height(height);
}
```

**CSS**

```
.right {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="row">


    <div class="col-md-8 left">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora adipisci quidem itaque, reiciendis minima! Unde, in est. Cumque, voluptates, facilis. Earum magnam et error modi, numquam quo? Beatae, vel placeat. Dignissimos, neque, eos! In quasi et laboriosam nam vero quia rem placeat. Asperiores iusto magni eos ipsam veritatis? Eaque, quisquam!</p>

        <span style="color:white">Wash-type</span>
        <form>
            <!-- dummy data-->
            <label class="customCheckbox"><input type ="radio"  name="r1" value="r1"><span>Option 1</span></label>
            <label class="customCheckbox"><input type ="radio" name="r1" value="r2"><span>Option 2</span></label>
            <label class="customCheckbox"><input type ="radio" name="r1" value="r2"><span>option 3</span></label>
            <label class="customCheckbox"><input type ="radio" name="r1" value="r2"><span>Option 4</span></label>
        </form>


    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 right">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>

                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Service Option</th>
                        <th>Price <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora adipisci quidem itaque, reiciendis minima! Unde, in est. Cumque, voluptates, facilis. Earum magnam et error modi, numquam quo? Beatae, vel placeat. Dignissimos, neque, eos! In quasi et laboriosam nam vero quia rem placeat. Asperiores iusto magni eos ipsam veritatis? Eaque, quisquam!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora adipisci quidem itaque, reiciendis minima! Unde, in est. Cumque, voluptates, facilis. Earum magnam et error modi, numquam quo? Beatae, vel placeat. Dignissimos, neque, eos! In quasi et laboriosam nam vero quia rem placeat. Asperiores iusto magni eos ipsam veritatis? Eaque, quisquam!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora adipisci quidem itaque, reiciendis minima! Unde, in est. Cumque, voluptates, facilis. Earum magnam et error modi, numquam quo? Beatae, vel placeat. Dignissimos, neque, eos! In quasi et laboriosam nam vero quia rem placeat. Asperiores iusto magni eos ipsam veritatis? Eaque, quisquam!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora adipisci quidem itaque, reiciendis minima! Unde, in est. Cumque, voluptates, facilis. Earum magnam et error modi, numquam quo? Beatae, vel placeat. Dignissimos, neque, eos! In quasi et laboriosam nam vero quia rem placeat. Asperiores iusto magni eos ipsam veritatis? Eaque, quisquam!</p> </th>

                    </tr>

                </thead>
                <tbody>

                </tbody>
            </div>
        </div>

    </table>

 </div>
```

Comment: This is the last option. I was wondering if there is any way to achieve it using CSS only. Thanks :)